# Response time calculation in SJF NON PREEMPTIVE

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, scheduling

process------  arrival------ burst_time
p1                      0                   3
p2                      1                   4
p3                      2                   5

I'm confused about the response time calculation. To calculate the response time is the arrival need to subtract or not? And what's the solution of this?

Comment: You need to provide more info.

Comment: Since there are no non-preemptive schedulers in common use, how is this useful to future visitors?

Comment: @MartinJames I faced a question in a question paper of operating system to calculate response time.

Comment: @onetwo12 what more info need here?